# Getting undefined is not an object error when making sinon stub in Angular

Tags: angularjs, sinon, stub, karma-mocha, sinon-chai

I have the following testing code:

```
describe('imagesCtrl', function () {
    var $rootScope;
    var $compile;
    var $log;
    var $controller;
    var imagesCtrl;
    var $q;
    var images;
    var vm;

beforeEach(module('flickrPOC'));

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {

    $provide.service('images', function () {
        this.loadPics = sinon.stub().returns($q.resolve({message: 'object data from stub'}));
    });

}));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$log_, _$controller_, _$q_, _images_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $log = _$log_;
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $q = _$q_;
    images = _images_;

    vm = $controller('imagesCtrl');

}));

describe('imagesCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        images.loadPics.returns($q.resolve({message: 'd'}));
    });

    it('should exist', function () {
        expect(vm.getImages).to.exist();
    }
});
});
```

I am injecting an controller, that is setup as follows:

```
(function (angular) {
angular
    .module('flickrPOC')
    .controller('imagesCtrl', imagesCtrl);

imagesCtrl.$inject = ['images', '$compile', '$http', '$q'];

function imagesCtrl(images, $compile, $http, $q) {
    /* jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;

    vm.getImages = function () {
        images.loadPics()
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                vm.images = res.name;
            })
            .catch(
                function(err){
                    console.error('Error loading images ', err.status, err.data);
                })
            .finally(function () {
                console.log("finally finished");
            });
    };
}

})(angular);
```

When the test is ran, i get the following error:

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) imagesCtrl "before each" hook: workFn for "should exist" FAILED
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$q.resolve')
            at..src/js/controllers/imageCtrl-test.js:18;

this error refers to the line
    this.loadPics = sinon.stub().returns($q.resolve({.....}));

Answer (score 0):

so the answer was on the dependency injection. 
At first i was trying to inject $q at the before each as:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide, $q) {

    $provide.service('images', function () {
        this.loadPics = sinon.stub().returns($q.resolve({message: 'object data from service stub'}));
    });

}));
```

the right way to do it is injecting it to the $provider as follows:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {

    $provide.service('images', function ($q) {
        this.loadPics = sinon.stub().returns($q.resolve({message: 'object data from service stub'}));
    });

}));
```

After this, everything works fine.